# Why two successive page opens with segue

Tags: swift, uitableview

when I am selected button twice will open a new page.

//////

> Main viewController

```
var Country = [] 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
 @IBAction func taxiAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        let opt = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
        Country = opt

        performSegueWithIdentifier("viewPlaceSegu", sender: sender)
    }
...
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    if segue.identifier == "viewPlaceSegu" {
        if let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? TableViewPlace {

    // set a variable in the second view controller with the String to pass
            secondViewController.tnt = Country as! [String]
        }

    }
}
```

////
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKrN7.jpg

I tried so but didn't realize problem .

Does anyone know about this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A likely cause is that you have connected the segue from the button to the new ViewController in the storyboard. When the button is pressed it will load the segue created in storyboard as well as the one created programatically.

If this is the cause then you would just need to delete the storyboard segue and create a new one from the ViewController rather than from the button.

Comment: can you tell us more ؟

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without seeing the project. Did you connect the segue by dragging from the button to the destination view controller?

If you did, delete that segue. Then create a segue from the first view controller by control dragging from the yellow circle at the top of the view, over to the other view controller.